# Web service not fetching data

Tags: php, web-services

When i test my code in localhost (i.e code and webservice is on local) then everything is working fine but when we move code to server i am not getting data from webservice.

following message is occured.
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found.

```
<?php $Name=file_get_contents('web service call');

$output= json_decode($Name);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means the URL that `file_get_contents()` called, was not found.

When you moved the code to the server, did you move the 'web service' too? If the location has changed, you need to update it in the `file_get_contents()` call.

Comment: yes i move webservice.... my webservice from javascript are working but from php ... not working